# Right click folder in Windows Explorer and Search with Total Commander?

Tags: windows-explorer, total-commander

I often use Total Commander to search files and folder in windows. Is there a way to set a right click option to open Total Commander and have it automatically set to search the folder i'm in?

For now I have to copy the folder location from Explorer's folder path at the top of the window and paste it into Total Commander. I'm looking for any short cuts to minimize these steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found an easier approach without changing the registry (below I'm paraphrasing a post by ts4242 at this link https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=43637 ):

> Add a shortcut to totalcmd.exe inside your profile's "Send to" folder

The "Send to" folder is found here for modern Windows OS versions:
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\

Then you can right click the folder and choose "Send to" > "Total Commander" and this will open the directory in a new instance of Total Commander.

If you want to open the directory in the current instance of Total Commander, then change the target of the shortcut you created to 
C:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD.EXE /O /L="%1"

Answer (score 1):

You can save following contents as a .reg file and add it to register by double-clicking your .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Total_Commander]
@="Search file contents here"
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-177"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Total_Commander\command]
@="\"C:\\TotalCmd\\TOTALCMD.EXE\" /S=F \"%1\""
```

NOTE:
**C:\\TotalCmd\\TOTALCMD.EXE** should be replaced with your total commander path.

Comment: The only downside, it that you can't use Go to file button, since main window of TC is not created.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer in Total Commanders Wiki goes over a few versions of windows

http://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/Explorer_integration

Answer (score 0):

Use the TCShell utility to set the required registry options for you: http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/tcshell.html